# ADODB not properly installed on Win7-64?

Tags: ado.net

My .net windows forms app won't run on Windows 7 64 bit. Error says ADODB not found. Giving it the dll (by putting it in with the program) then gives error that ADODB provider is not properly installed. How to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like maybe you're using classic ado rather than ado.net (even if you call it from a .net program).  But without any code, we can't know for sure.

Comment: Does it work on windows 7 32bit? If so it might be a 32/64 bit issue with something like COM. Ensure you build your app as 32bit and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app must run as a 32 bit process as OLEDB is not supported in 64 bit processes.